# How to update XML file using Ajax + Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest

I want to update the XML file using Ajax & jquery. I am new to ajax so tried with using both POST/PUT.

For PUT: I am getting the error 405. i.e "Method Not Found"
For POST: Bad Request

vvmsUrl: is the path to xml file

Our get is working fine, but not the PUT/POST.

PUT Code:

vvmsUrl: is the path to xml file

```
var XMLData= "<origin>ABCbfk</origin>";
       jQuery.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: vvmsUrl,
        contentType: "application/xml",
        headers: { 'Prefer' : 'persistent-auth',
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PUT'},
        dataType: "xml",
        processData: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: XMLData,
        success:function(msg)
        {
           alert("hello"+msg);
        },
        error: function(msg){
        alert("Error"+msg);
        LOG(xhr.status);
        }
    });
```

I am stuck from 2 days. I am not getting what goes wrong in this.

Comment: The issue was finally solved. The issue was with the "data:XMLDATA". It was not in correct XML format

Answer (score 0):

You can try : upload any file

HTML code

```
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile" />
<input type="button" value="upload" onclick="upload()" />
```

Javascript code

```
<script>
   var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

   function upload() 
   {
     var file = document.getElementById("uploadfile");

     /* Create a FormData instance */
     var formData = new FormData();
     /* Add the file */ 
     formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);

     client.open("post", "/upload", true);
     client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
     client.send(formData);  /* Send to server */ 
     }

     /* Check the response status */  
     client.onreadystatechange = function() 
     {
      if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) 
       {
         alert(client.statusText);
       }
      }
</script>
```

Comment: We are trying to update the XML file not the html file.

Comment: so you should change "XML file" to "XML data"

Answer (score 0):

You need a server side script to handle modifications to anything at the server you cannot just use client side jQuery. The script will also check who is authorized to write to the file or otherwise anyone can modify/update your XML file which is a security problem and probably is what you don't want.

Please could you include all of your code? I mean what is `vvmUrl` ? Are you using some web service? Is your code making call to another domain, why `crossDomain: true`?

**EDIT:**
This should work in jQuery 1.7.2+

```
var username = 'myUser';
var password = 'myPassword';

$.ajax
({
  type: "PUT",
  url: vvmsUrl,
  contentType: 'application/xml',
  async: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  username: username,
  password: password,
  data: xmlData,
  success: function (){
    alert('Works!'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: I was geting some "Method not Found" error. So I had added crossDomain: true. My GET code is working fine. But I am not able to do PUT/POST. We had done the similar code using curl which works fine.

Comment: `GET` will work fine as it **isn't** doing any changes to the file on server. Your `vvmsUrl` is the link to the file, the file is on server, correct? So to update that file you'll need server side language. You can't POST data to XML file.

Comment: curl -X PUT -H "Accept: application/xml" \
                -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -u ${arguser}:${argpass} \
                --cacert ${CERTFILE} -d@"${datafile}" ${url} \
                >${file} 2>/dev/null

Comment: have a look at modified answer. you need to include usename and password in your ajax call.

Comment: I tried executing the above code, but one screen pops up asking username & password. But, even if I enter the username & password it keeps me asking again & again the same.